# Корректно и быстро записать список словарей в txt-файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, инспекция-кода, python-3.6

Имеется такой список словарей:

```
result = [{'1st_k': '1st_v', '2nd_k': '2nd_v', '3rd_k': '3rd_v'},
          {'1st-k': '1st-v', '2nd-k': '2nd-v', '3rd-k': '3rd-v'},
          {'1st.k': '1st.v', '2nd.k': '2nd.v', '3rd.k': '3rd.v'}]
```

Каким образом его правильнее записать в текстовый файл, чтобы получилось что-то такое:

```
1st_k: 1st_v
2nd_k: 2nd_v
3rd_k: 3rd_v

1st-k: 1st-v
2nd-k: 2nd-v
3rd-k: 3rd-v

1st.k: 1st.v
2nd.k: 2nd.v
3rd.k: 3rd.v
```

То есть каждая пара `ключ: значение` словаря должна записываться на новой строке, а между каждым словарем должна стоять пустая строка. Пока что я записываю вот так:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for record in result:
        for key, value in record.items():
            file.write(f'\n{key}: {value}')
        file.write('\n')
```

Но я не знаю, насколько это эффективно, плюс в начале и в конце файла у меня образуются пустые строки, которые мне приходится обрезать. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант очень похожий на ваше решение:

```
In [174]: def f(d):
     ...:     return '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items())
     ...:

In [175]: txt = '\n\n'.join(map(f, result))

In [176]: print(txt)
1st_k: 1st_v
2nd_k: 2nd_v
3rd_k: 3rd_v

1st-k: 1st-v
2nd-k: 2nd-v
3rd-k: 3rd-v

1st.k: 1st.v
2nd.k: 2nd.v
3rd.k: 3rd.v
```

ну и запись в файл:

```
file.write(txt)
```

Если есть сомнения, что `txt` поместится в памяти, то лучше писать в файл по одному элементу.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение достаточно эффективно: при вводе-выводе производительность больше зависит не от кода, а от скорости внешнего устройства.

Чтобы не образовывались пустые строки в начале, делайте перенос строки не до вывода, а после:

```
file.write(f'{key}: {value}\n')
```

Могу еще предложить использовать `print` вместо `write`, тогда перенос строки будет добавляться автоматически (опять же, в конце выводимой строки):

```
print(f'{key}: {value}', file=file)
```

Если лишний перенос строки в конце файла очень мешает, то можно добавить проверку, что выводится последний словарь, и если это так, то не делать после него перевод строки:

```
for i, record in enumerate(result):
    for key, value in record.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}', file=file)

    if i < len(result)-1:  # Для длины N элементов последний элемент будет иметь индекс N-1
        print(file=file)
```